# html inside php mail

Tags: php, html, email

I have the following html codes for my email.

```
$headers = "From: jmedalla20@gmail.com \r\n" .
   "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
   "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 \r\n"; 
$message = <<<EOD
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=text/html; charset=utf-8 />
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=logo.jpg/>
</head>
<body>

<img src=../../img/logo.jpg style=left: 0;position: absolute; width: 75px;/>
<body style=padding: 0 0 0 100px;position: relative;>
{date(F d, Y )}  <br><br>

<b> {$row_Recordset1['First Name']}&nbsp{$row_Recordset1['Middle Initial']}&nbsp{$row_Recordset1['Last Name']}</b><br>
{$row_Recordset1['Position']}<br>{$row_Recordset1['Company Name']}<br>{$row_Recordset1['Corporate Address']}<br><br>

<p>Dear {$row_Recordset1['Last Name']}:</p>
// the rest of the letters
</body>
</html>
EOD;
```

I've had a few test runs and all that displays is

```
{date(F d, Y )}



Dear :
```

I don't think the codes are being recognized. Any suggestions?

EDIT: The html is working. it's just the php codes which are not working I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you cannot insert function calls like that. To insert the date, create a variable before this snippet of code that says `$date = date()`. Then you can use that variable in the string.

Apparently `$row_Recordset1['Last Name']` is empty, doesn't exist, contains an empty string or whitespace or a piece of HTML. Hard to tell what exactly, since we don't have your data, nor the piece of code that assigns a value to $row_Recordset1.

Nevertheless, the e-mail is interpreted as HTML, or otherwise you would see chunks of HTML instead of merely this text. So that part is working well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's not empty since I have a confirmation page which echoes those variables and they do appear in my confirmation page. I just resaved(?) the file as another script containing my mail functions. That is okay isn't it?

Comment: turns out you were right. I guess I need to find a way to pass values from one page to another. I've successfully done that to my confirmation page but the email certainly isn't getting the $_GET value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending an email with some basic html to see if it works? Your other code is probably screwing things up some how.

Comment: how is this an "answer" ..? You're not providing any solution

Comment: Troubleshooting is a process of elimination. He's just edited his post stating that HTML by itself works, so this changes the whole question. I don't often answer questions on SO, so if there is some rule I've broken then it's news to me.

Comment: It's common for answers to contain answers or maybe alternative solutions. Tips like these are usually written in comments, because, seful as they may be to the OP, they do not answer the question.

Comment: @GolezTrol well said, and no offense meant, it was a good advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers = "From: jmedalla20@gmail.com \r\n" .
   "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
   "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 \r\n";

$message = <<<EOD
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=text/html; charset=utf-8 />
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=logo.jpg/>
</head>
<body>
<img src=../../img/logo.jpg style=left: 0;position: absolute; width: 75px;/>
<body style=padding: 0 0 0 100px;position: relative;>
EOD;

$message .= date("F d, Y ")."<br><br>";

    $message .= "<b>".$row_Recordset1['First Name']."&nbsp".$row_Recordset1['Middle Initial']."&nbsp".$row_Recordset1['Last Name']."</b><br>";
$message .= $row_Recordset1['Position']."<br>".$row_Recordset1['Company Name']."<br>".$row_Recordset1['Corporate Address']."<br><br>";
$message .= "<p>Dear ".$row_Recordset1['Last Name'].":</p>";
// the rest of the letters
$message .= "</body>
</html>";
```

Comment: Break up that reasonably nice heredoc string? Waste. Just use a variable. They're not that scary. You solution makes it only harder to maintain this e-mail and moves it one step away from starting to use templates.

Comment: It did show up the date but the rest of the variables are still not working. Thanks for the help btw. Anything is appreciated.

Comment: The output is still the same :(

Comment: check your getting data from database , `$message .= date("F d, Y ")."<br><br>".print_r($row_Recordset1,true);